# Call method even if a button is disabled in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a button which is disabled based on certain condition in Angular. I would like to enable the `onclick` functionality even if the button is disabled. Please find the below code:

```
<button
  *ngIf="overrideSplitByAccountEnabled && 
  (!overrideSplitByaccountListOfAcc && 
  !overrideSplitByAccountGroupValue) || ((isStartTimeInputPresent && 
  !isValidStartTimestamp) || (isEndTimeInputPresent && 
  !isValidEndTimestamp))"
  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
  (click)="validateCustomReRunParameters()" disabled>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" ></i>
  Send action
</button>
```

Here even if button is disabled i would like to enable click to `validateCustomReRunParameters()`

I tried on click but not working as the button is disabled.

Comment: This is not possible. If you want to click on a disable button, you have to give it a disabled styling.

Comment: Why bother clicking on a disabled button? Just enable it from the beginning if you plan to use it!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a `div` around the `button` and attach a click event to that `div`. If the button is disabled, the wrapper `div` will take the width and height of the `button`. When a user clicks on the disabled `button`, the `div` event will be triggered. If the `button` is enabled, the width and height of the `div` will be set to 0.
something like this :

```
<div (click)="validateCustomReRunParameters()">
  <button
    *ngIf="overrideSplitByAccountEnabled && 
    (!overrideSplitByaccountListOfAcc && 
    !overrideSplitByAccountGroupValue) || ((isStartTimeInputPresent && 
    !isValidStartTimestamp) || (isEndTimeInputPresent && 
    !isValidEndTimestamp))"
    type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
    (click)="validateCustomReRunParameters()" disabled>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" ></i>
    Send action
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: That won't work. [StackBlitzExample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mouquu?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @MrXQ [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77778159/7970858) here is your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-shiybv?file=src%2Fmain.ts) updated. html mask concept has been used to make this work